# ember - closure action results in error, will not render page unless action is provided in component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to understand closure actions and am just testing out some code, however I can't seem to get it to work. In my `index.hbs` template I have rendered a component like so:

```
{{test-component test=(action 'foo')}}
```

In my `index.js` controller I have defined the action `foo`:

```
  foo: function () {
    console.log('foo executed');
  },
```

And in my `test-component.hbs` component I have a button that triggers the action like so:

```
<button {{action (action 'test')}}>Test Button</button>.
```

However the page crashes and I get the following error in the console: `Uncaught Error: An action named 'test' was not found`

I can make the page render again by inserting a `test` action in the `test-component.hbs` however I was under the impression that you using closure actions, you didn't need to put anything in your component? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way you can think about closure actions is just passing function references.

In your given code, when you say

```
{{test-component test=(action 'foo')}}
```

You are basically saying

> Grab the action `'foo'` from the current context and pass it as the property `test`

which in pseudo-code for your specific example could look like:

```
{{test-component test=IndexController.actions.foo}}
```

That means property `test` within `test-component` points to the same function that is the action `foo` in the `index` controller.

Thus, you would just use it directly:

```
// test is an action passed into test-component
<button {{action test}}>Test Button</button>.
```

Here's a simple [EmberTwiddle example](https://ember-twiddle.com/66c0960b4abebf9c89ff4e6a8b69fe39?openFiles=templates.components.test-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.test-component.hbs).

When you say `{{action (action 'test')}}` within your `test-component`, its looking for the action `test` within its current context, which is the component itself and the component doesn't have an action `test`, it has a property called `test` which happens to point to an action from its outer context, the `index` controller.

Comment: Thanks. The syntax I was using in my component, is that to be used in a different situation?

Comment: Yes. I've mentioned that in the last paragraph of my answer. That syntax is to call an action from the current context, so the component itself. It is the similar syntax you use when you pass `foo` into `test-component`, and there you use it to call an action on the `index` controller. Although its redundant to say `{{action (action 'actionName')}}`, all you would need is `{{action 'actionName'}}`. The `action` helper, i.e. `(action 'actionName')` is used to pass actions around while `{{action 'actionName'}}` is used to call actions in the current context